# Classic ASP getting ODBC Drivers error '80004005' on Win7 x32 with IIS7.5

Tags: mysql, windows-7, asp-classic, iis-7.5

I am trying to set up my PC as a test/debug base for my Classic ASP sites. The OS is Win7 32 bit with IIS7.5.

The ASP pages work until I try to talk to the MySQL db which is located at my hosts server. The error I'm getting is:

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no
>   default driver specified

And the error seems to be at:

```
Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
strConn = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver}; SERVER=1.2.3.4; DATABASE=******; UID=*******;PASSWORD=******; OPTION=3;"
objConn.Open strConn
```

I know the code is fine because it works at the host.

Wondering if this is a permissions issue?

Comment: Is the MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver definitely installed? Is this definitely a 32 bit edition of Windows?

Comment: Just to clarify is the actual OS 32 bit or are you running the Application Pool in IIS in 32 Bit mode? If it is the latter the Driver could be installed into the 64 bit registry while the Application Pool is looking in the 32 bit registry for the data source and not finding it.

Comment: I had the 5.3 driver installed... doh! But now getting the error [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver]Connection using old (pre-4.1.1) authentication protocol refused (client option 'secure_auth' enabled) . Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @CPAndo1974  I would suggest installing the same version of driver that you have on the server, otherwise you will have all sorts of issues.  Been there done that.   There is a setting on MySQL database that allows the older password encryption (which is what that error is about).